# Problem With NDSolve, Mathematica does not run

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Hello everybody I was solving an exercise that its solution was the solution of a system of differential equations but when executing the command in mathematics this takes a long time and then the message appears that the data could not be stored in the notebook

Could someone help me with this little problem please?

```
k1 = 55.20;
k2 = 30.20;
NDSolve[{Ch'[\[Tau]] + k1*(Ch[\[Tau]])^0.5*Cm[\[Tau]] + 
    k2*Cx[\[Tau]]*(Ch[\[Tau]])^0.5 == 0, 
  Cm'[\[Tau]] + k1*Cm[\[Tau]]*(Ch[\[Tau]])^0.5 == 0, 
  Cx'[\[Tau]] - k1 + Cm[\[Tau]]*(Ch[\[Tau]])^0.5 + 
    k2*Cx[\[Tau]]*(Ch[\[Tau]])^0.5 == 0, Ch[0] == 0.021, 
  Cm[0] == 0.0105, Cx[0] == 0}, {Ch, Cm, Cx}, {\[Tau], 0, 0.5}]
```

Comment: Do you also get the following:  `NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 1555386 steps reached at the point \[Tau] == 0.01866285900051184`.` ?

Comment: "...message appears that the data could not be stored in the notebook..."
Do you mean the "Data not in notebook. Store now ->" messages? If so, that's not a problem, it's just offering to save the data as part of the notebook for future use, precluding the need to re-run the lengthy generation.

Comment: In your 3rd equation, $k_1 + C_m$ looks suspicious.  Should it be $k_1 * C_m$ ?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2300187.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, indeed the expression was as @LouisB said and thanks @ Tim Laska I had not thought of using NDSolveValue as a list, I generally saved it in a single variable and then separated that variable into the other variables that I was interested in, thanks , Thank you very much for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @LouisB answered the question with his comment. I will just add that the problem looks like a chemical kinetics problem and that this could be a good application of [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to simplify the problem and help avoid typos.

```
k1 = 55.20;
k2 = 30.20;
With[{r1 = k1*(Ch[τ])^0.5*Cm[τ], 
  r2 = k2*Cx[τ]*(Ch[τ])^0.5},
 {Chfun, Cmfun, Cxfun} = 
   NDSolveValue[{Ch'[τ] + r1 + r2 == 0, Cm'[τ] + r1 == 0, 
     Cx'[τ] - r1 + r2 == 0, Ch[0] == 0.021, Cm[0] == 0.0105, 
     Cx[0] == 0}, {Ch, Cm, Cx}, {τ, 0, 1}];]
Plot[{Chfun[t], Cmfun[t], Cxfun[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]